# Getting audio to play on my site using html5

Tags: audio

I am a complete novice and am studying HTML5 and CSS.

I am building a simple web page (on my local computer not a server) on my C:/ drive to play a musical audio with controls.

My speakers and sound work fine when I am on any website, etc. but I cannot get this web page to play my audio file. All I get is a hiss.

I have searched and searched for what my problem is but cannot find it.

Here is my html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>audio.html</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Audio Demo</h1>
<audio controls = "controls">
<source src = "0124.wav" type="audio/wav">
<source src = "0124.mp3" type="audio/mp3">

</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

I would certainly appreciate any assistance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The browser can be called the client - everything it can show you lives on some server.  Luckily you can use your computer as a server.  Put into the same directory where your above html file lives those wav and mp3 files.  Then just point your browser at the full path to reach your html file (your URL) similar to

```
file:///home/scott/Documents/data/audio/play.html
```

evidently to show both files you may wish arrange as :

```
<audio controls = "controls">
<source src = "0124.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
<br>
<audio controls = "controls">
<source src = "0124.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Scott. I already have the audio files in the same directory as my html files but they still won't play. I have tested the audio files on Windows Media Player and they play fine. I just am at a loss.

Comment: I do not use Windows so cannot replicate this.  Try using firefox  -  Also if you have python installed paste this into a command window in that same dir :  python -m SimpleHTTPServer  8888    then if your html file is called say play.html then  go to URL  http://localhost:8888/play.html    this runs a tiny http server which will make visible all files in the directory --- Oh btw install linux ;-)

Comment: Scott I appreciate your assistance. I have done exactly as you have described and nothing will play. Also, after altering my html as you suggested the first control shows up and stays up. The second control briefly flashed on the screen and then disappears.

Comment: I just now saw your latest answer. I don't have Python and am trying to keep things as simple as I can as I am a total novice in programming. I am using Firefox.